# how to boot openIndiana with grub

Tags: grub2, openindiana

I have grub controlled by debian
But I installed open-indiana in a partition sda10 
What do I have to include in grub 40.custom that open-indiana boots
; partition table is msdos

Answer (score 0):

*I just tried with `chain loader` and it works*

```
menuentry "OI-hipster" {

        set root=(hd0,10)
        chainloader +1
}
```

`hdX` will be your harddisk number
and 10 is partition number